# Setting state inside of axios function call, then call function in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, axios

I am using React functional components.
I am setting state inside of an axios call, then calling the function in useEffect hook.

Here is my function:

```js
import { useDispatch } from “react-redux”;

functon ABCComponent({ navigation }){

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
    const testPostID = "1234567891011";
    
    const [post, setPost] = useState("");

     const getPostById = async(postID)=>{
        await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/posts/post/${postID}`)
            .then((response) =>{
                dispatch(setLoading(true));
                dispatch(setSuccess(true));
                dispatch(setLoading(false));
                response.data.message.map((post, index) =>{
            
                    setPost(post); // I think it's complaining about this line
                });
            }).catch((error) =>{
                console.log("err: ", error);
                dispatch(setLoading(true));
                dispatch(setSuccess(false));
                dispatch(setLoading(false));
                dispatch(setMessage(`${error}`));
            });
    };

    useEffect(() =>{
        getPostById(testPostID);
    }, []);
    
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> **Warning**: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function,
> in ABCComponent.

**What I tried:**
I tried removing async/await hoping that it would solve the problem, but it didn’t.

what is the best way to go about solving this?

Comment: Use axios cancellation on unmount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory leak can occur when you are trying to update state on unmounted component, like the warning said. In order to fix this you should include some `isMounted` flag that you will use in order to check whether component is still mounted, before updating state. Also there are few other suggests I would give you - do not use async/await with .then, you should use only one of these two approach(async/await is my suggestion).

You should rewrite to something like this:

```
const isMounted = useRef(true);
const testPostID = "1234567891011";

const [post, setPost] = useState("");

const getPostById = async(postID)=>{
      try {
        dispatch(setLoading(true));

        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/posts/post/${postID}`)
        
        if(isMounted.current){
            dispatch(setSuccess(true));
            dispatch(setLoading(false));
            response.data.message.map((post, index) =>{
                 setPost(post); // This part is unclear, why overriding state, and why in .map???
            });
         }
       } catch(err) {
         console.log("err: ", error);
         if(isMounted.current) {              
           dispatch(setLoading(true));
           dispatch(setSuccess(false));
           dispatch(setLoading(false));
           dispatch(setMessage(`${error}`));
         }
       }
  };

useEffect(() =>{
    getPostById(testPostID);

   return () => {
     isMounted.current = false;
   }
}, []);
```

Also there is one unclear part where you are updating state, why using .map and why overriding state in each iteration?